# ROS Answers SE migration: How to Start

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I have a question about ROS architecture and how to start up a nee robotic software.
I understand how ROS is organized about nodes, msgs, subscribers and so on.

After that my question is, I have a node that is related to a sensor and this sensor publish data. I have another module that will be its subscriber. My doubt is related to the usage of this data and how can I create my program, where can I insert my behavior.

Will this data be used by my custom application that is aware about the message and how to parse it ? or can I use other more complex nodes? in this case how can I customize the software?

I have not found any information about to start up a new software? I mean about the first step and high level point of view of the architecture.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61424/how-to-start/) by [mbelloli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4746/mbelloli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the [ROS Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are the best starting point. Specifically number 11/12... but to get to those you should work the preceding ones.

If your application requires the creation of a custom message this would have been covered in tutorial 10.. but you should check the existing "standard" messages to make sure that you're not reinventing the wheel.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5